# Error on server SMTP - PEAR.php on line 557

Tags: php, email, smtp, pear

My application inquiry form is working on last 2 years 
But now I am fill all information on my inquiry page and submit

Expected: successfully send message

Actual: I don't get any email in my email account

I have to check my server log its some error 
error_log file

```
[21-Oct-2013 09:44:07 Europe/Minsk] PHP Deprecated:  Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in /home/public_html/includes/common/lib/email/Pear/PEAR.php on line 557
[21-Oct-2013 09:44:07 Europe/Minsk] PHP Deprecated:  Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in /home/public_html/includes/common/lib/email/Pear/PEAR.php on line 560
[21-Oct-2013 09:44:07 Europe/Minsk] PHP Deprecated:  Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in /home/public_html/includes/common/lib/email/Pear/Mail.php on line 134
[21-Oct-2013 09:44:07 Europe/Minsk] PHP Deprecated:  Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in /home/public_html/includes/common/lib/email/Pear/Mail/smtp.php on line 189
[21-Oct-2013 09:44:07 Europe/Minsk] PHP Deprecated:  Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in /home/public_html/includes/common/lib/email/Pear/Net/SMTP.php on line 127
```

Help me to sort out this issue

Comment: This are warnings, they do nothing bad to your code.

Comment: Can you tell me what is the issue

Comment: My enquiry form is not working with this issue can you short out

Answer (score 1):

Try to send mail with mail("somebody@example.com","My subject",$txt);

kindly check reference http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mail_mail.asp

there is showing error while value assign to the variable you have declare.kindly check